# Header authorization doesn't exist

Tags: json, express, authorization, token, request-headers

I'm trying to send a jwt token on my API but it doesn't work whereas i do the same thing as an internet course.
And it seems like the authorization header is undefined and don't take the token i give in a json response.

Here is a screenshot of my login function :

```
login(req:Request, res:Response) {
    const id = this._id;
    bcrypt.compare(req.query.password, this._password)
        .then(function (valid: any) {
            if (!valid) {
                return res.status(401).json({error: 'Mot de passe incorrect !'});
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                hostId: id,
                token: jwt.sign({hostId : id}, 'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET', {expiresIn: '12h'})
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error:any) {
                res.status(500).json({error})
            })
        .catch(function (error:any)  {
            res.status(500).json({error});
        });
}
```

And here is my authentification function :

```
static auth(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) {
    try {
        console.log('bonjour');
        console.log(req.headers.authorization);
        console.log(req.body.hostId);
        let token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET');
        const id = decodedToken.hostId;
        if (req.body.hostId && req.body.hostId !== id) {
            throw 'Invalid user ID';
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({error: error.message});
    }
}
```

And I have setup my headers in my server class :

```
export default class Server {
constructor() {
    app.use(function (req:Request, res:Response, next:any) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
        next();
    })
    .get('/', function (req:Request, res:Response) {
        res.send("Serveur démarré");
    })
    .listen(8080);
}
```

}

I'm using nodejs with express, mongoose for my db and typescript.

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set header as { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } in front-end side instead of server side

Comment: But how considering that it's an API so there is no frontend

Comment: The whole process is as: 1, Client sends '/login' request to server with name and password in the http-body.  2, Server checks the body params. If the params are correct, server response in "/login" api with an auth-token.   3. client receives the token and caches it. The following http requests sent by client should contain the token in header.  4. server checks each of the http requests' (login api itself is not included) header to make sure if client is an authorized user.

Comment: Ok thank you i understood so in my case in which i treat only server side requests and response i have to put the token in authorization header manually in a software like postman that's right ?